# If else not running on Boolean value

Tags: php, function, if-statement, boolean

Tried the below code. All I can ever get is "not working".

```
bp_is_my_profile();        //this is a Boolean.
echo bp_is_my_profile();      // this echo's out either one or nothing depending on true or false.

if ($bp_is_my_profile === "true") {      // I've tried putting in numbers one and zero.
  echo "Have a good morning!";
} elseif ($bp_is_my_profile === "false") {  // I've tried without quotes.
  echo "Have a good day!";
} else {
  echo "Not working";      //whatever the Boolean is, each's it prints this line of code.
}
```

Comment: `$bp_is_my_profile` is undefined. You have not stored any thing in `$bp_is_my_profile` in sample.

Comment: `$bp_is_my_profile = bp_is_my_profile();`

Comment: Running a function doesn't automatically set a variable.

Comment: As @s.wadhwa pointed out. You need to put that line of code before `if-else`, also change you `true-false` strings to boolean.

Comment: `===` will check for value and datatype as well. Even when `$bp_is_my_profile` is `true`, `$bp_is_my_profile === "true"` will return false because `"true"` is string type.

Answer (score 1):

Call the function in the `if`

```
if (bp_is_my_profile()) {
    echo "Have a good morning";
} else {
    echo "Have a good day";
}
```

You shouldn't compare with strings, since the function returns a boolean. And since it returns a boolean, there are only two possibilities, so you don't need three cases.